# How to loop through VF page fields and confirm that at least 2 are populated?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am building this VF page that has number of input fields, lookup field,and pick-list fields. What I am doing, is performing a REST call search on the inputs of these fields. I would like to add a validation, where I can run though the fields, and want to confirm that at least 2 are populated with values. The total number of fields is 9. I know how to accomplish this manually per say, where I check each combination, but I would think there must be a more efficient way of doing this. Could you please share any ideas?

Here is a sample code from my controller, that captures one of the permutations. I just think that there must be more efficient way of capturing all of the different permutations.

```
if(masterId==''&&this.companyName==''&&this.street==''&&this.city==''&&this.strState==null&&this.zip==''&&this.phone==''&&this.email==''&&acc.Regional_Chapter_Name__c==null){
            ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR, ' Need to enter additional search criteria: Constituent Name, Master ID, Region, City, State, Email, Phone or Zip Code.');
            ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg); 
            ExcecutedError = True;
}
```

Comment: We would need to see some code, since the answer will depend on the nature of the code you've written (e.g. Apex vs JavaScript). You don't need to post the unrelated parts, but some code would greatly help out here.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I just edited my question with sample code. I am just looking to on over all guidance on how I can approach this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Apex, you'd want to just keep a tally of non-empty fields.

Here's one way you could do this:

```
Integer totalPop = 0;
totalPop += String.isBlank(masterId)? 0: 1;
totalPop += String.isBlank(companyName)? 0: 1;
totalPop += String.isBlank(street)? 0: 1;
totalPop += String.isBlank(city)? 0: 1;
totalPop += String.isBlank(strState)? 0: 1;
totalPop += String.isBlank(zip)? 0: 1;
totalPop += String.isBlank(phone)? 0: 1;
totalPop += String.isBlank(acc.Regional_Chapter_Name__c)? 0: 1;
if(totalPop < 2) {
  ApexPages.addMessage(
    new ApexPages.Message(
      ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Please enter at least two values'
    )
  );
} else {
  // continue processing here...
}
```

Or, if you really insist on a loop:

```
String[] values =  new String[] {
  masterId, companyName, street, city, strState, zip, phone, acc.Regional_Chapter_Name__c
};
Integer totalPop = 0;
for(String value: values) {
  if(String.isNotBlank(value)) {
    totalPop++;
  }
}
if(totalPop < 2) {
  ApexPages.addMessage(
    new ApexPages.Message(
      ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Please enter at least two values'
    )
  );
} else {
  // continue processing here...
}
```

Comment: Great suggestions. Thank you  you very much !!!